# C++ Email cuts off when blank char is added

Tags: c++, libcurl

So basically what I'm trying to do is send a message with several variables included. If a condition is matched, a variable will be displayed as a message. Otherwise, it will be blank. I'm using libcurl for this and this is the current email message:

```
char chartest[] = "This is Message #1";
char chartest2[] = "This is Message #2";
char chartest3[] = "This is Message #3";
const char *payload_text[] = {
    "Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2010 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
    "To: " TO "\r\n",
    "From: " FROM "\r\n",
    "Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@"
    "rfcpedant>\r\n",
    "Subject: Test!\r\n",
    "\r\n",
    "Testing.\r\n",
    chartest, "\r\n",
    chartest2, "\r\n",
    chartest3, "\r\n",
    NULL
};
```

This will display:

```
Testing.
This is Message #1
This is Message #2
This is Message #3
```

This is what I want.

However, if I set one of the messages to blank (because I don't want the user to receive this message):

```
char chartest[] = "This is Message #1";
char chartest2[] = "";
char chartest3[] = "This is Message #3";
const char *payload_text[] = {
    "Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2010 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
    "To: " TO "\r\n",
    "From: " FROM "\r\n",
    "Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@"
    "rfcpedant>\r\n",
    "Subject: Test!\r\n",
    "\r\n",
    "Testing.\r\n",
    chartest, "\r\n",
    chartest2, "\r\n",
    chartest3, "\r\n",
    NULL
};
```

It will display:

```
Testing.
This is Message #1
```

For some reason, it skips `Message #3`.

How could I implement this to skip certain messages or extra text without skipping the rest of the message entirely?

**EDIT:**

This is the example I'm using. Aside from the message (and added char values) the code is the same.

https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/examples/smtp-tls.c

I also editted the code slightly.

```
char chartest[] = "This is Message #1";
char chartest2[] = "This is Message #2";
char chartest3[] = "This is Message #3";
const char *payload_text[] = {
    "Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2010 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
    "To: " TO "\r\n",
    "From: " FROM "\r\n",
    "Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@"
    "rfcpedant>\r\n",
    "Subject: Test!\r\n",
    "\r\n",
    "Testing.", chartest, chartest2, chartest3, "\r\n",
    NULL
};
```

Unfortunately, this is still a problem.

**EDIT 2:**

I'm wondering if maybe `chartest2` is seen as "NULL" thus prematurely ending the message before the actual NULL. If that's the case, then I wonder how I would set a blank (but not null) char.

Comment: This depends what you're doing with that data. I don't see a libcurl function that directly takes an array of C strings.

Comment: You might take a look at the RFC for e-mail. Pretty sure `\r\n\r\n` ends the message depending on how you're sending it.

Comment: I changed the code so \r\n\r\n will no longer be a possibility, but this is still a problem. I also linked the original example I'm basing this on.

Comment: @RetiredNinja `\r\n\r\n` DOES NOT end the email. It does, however, separate the email headers from the email body.

Comment: @Jazael `""` and `NULL` are completely different things. There is no way the compiler would confuse one for the other. Looking at the code you linked to, I see nothing that would cause the behavior you describe (I do, however, see a small logic hole in its use of `memcpy()` in `payload_source()` but that is not important in this example). The problem has to be in your own code. Did you step through your code with a debugger to see what it is really doing?

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's been a long time since I've sent an e-mail via telnet. :) Thanks for the clarification!